# Will I be able to declare a constexpr lambda inside a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17

I know it's like opening the Pandora box but it doesn't stop bothering me. Consider a simple example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <auto>
struct Foo: std::false_type { };

template <>
struct Foo<[](){return 1;}()>:std::true_type { };

int main() {
    static_assert(Foo<1>::value);
}
```

I know lambdas cannot be declared inside unevaluated context, but obviously this is not the case here. What is even more weird clang 5.0.0 (which, I guess, first partially supports constexpr lambda) [does compile it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IUISuUO7slQcURFF).

Is it a compiler bug or will C++17 allow this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, that is a compiler bug. [gcc 7.1](https://godbolt.org/g/0HToIg) correctly rejects the code.

[[expr.prim.lambda]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda#2):

> A lambda-expression is a prvalue whose result object is called the *closure object*. A lambda-expression shall not appear in an unevaluated operand, **in a template-argument**, in an alias-declaration, in a typedef declaration, or in the declaration of a function or function template outside its function body and default arguments.

As you can see from the part that I marked as bold, a lambda expression cannot appear in a template argument list.

This is also made clear in a subsequent note:

> [ Note: The intention is to prevent lambdas from appearing in a signature. — end note ]

If I were to guess, I would say that the bug comes about because starting with C++17, lambdas are implicitly `constexpr`, which makes them valid to be called in compile time expressions, like template arguments. But actually defining a lambda in a template argument is still illegal.

---

Note that this restriction has been lifted in C++20. :)

Comment: yep I thought the standard committee intention was to present it, that's why I was surprised clang did compiler the code. I'll wait a bit and then accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea as to *why* this has been made illegal? Seems pretty useful, making meta programming a lot easier...

Comment: @DanielJour No, sorry. But that would make meta programming even *more* confusing :)

Comment: Is it official?

Comment: @W.F. Jup, the paragraph I'm quoting is gone :) http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#2

Comment: Nice finding! Thanks for sharing! Lets hope coders will use it reasonably ;)

Comment: Wait! Now lambda can be declared in decltype? :o

Comment: @W.F. Yes, finally :)

Comment: Wow! Cool wind of changes!

Comment: @DanielJour It seems like the committee agreed and in C++20 it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

In C++17 you can pass pointer to lambda function as template parameter with function pointer type:

```cpp
# include <cassert>

template<int(*fn)()>
int get_twice()
{
    return fn() * 2;
}

int main()
{
    int result = get_twice <+[]() { return 42; }> ();
    assert(result == 84);
}
```